# Implementation of interface when using child class of a parent class in method of interface

Tags: c#

I don't have access to my dev environment, but when I write the below:

```
interface IExample
 void Test (HtmlControl ctrl);



 class Example : IExample
 {
     public void Test (HtmlTextArea area) { }
```

I get an error stating the methods in the class implementation don't match the interface - so this is not possible. HtmlTextArea is a child class of HtmlControl, is there no way this is possible? I tried with .NET 3.5, but .NET 4.0 may be different (I am interested in any solution with either framework).

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
interface IExample<T> where T : HtmlControl
{
    void Test (T ctrl) ;
}

public class Example : IExample<HtmlTextArea>
{
    public void Test (HtmlTextArea ctrl) 
    { 
    }
}
```

Note for Charles:
You can use generic to get strongly typed method, otherwise you do not need to change signature of the method in child class, but just call it with any child of `HtmlControl`

Comment: My line of thinking is that, like a method signature which takes an Interface object, I can pass any any child implementation in a call to the method. I didn't actually think I need generics in this example.

Comment: @dotnetdev: than you do not need to change signature of method in child class. just pass any child that inherit from `HtmlControl` to Test method and it would work, regardless is this table or anchor. That's one of the main OOP principle - polymorphism

Comment: This is wrong and should NOT be the accepted answer. This won't even compile. Please check your answer and correct it. @dotnetdev: Please reconsider accepting this answer, since not only is it wrong, it has no explanation at all. This will be unhelpful to future readers of this question.

Comment: @Charles M: are you that sure about compilation? what if we use it in our projects for years?

Comment: vittore: did you know that I can see all of your revisions? Including revision 4 where you said "Fixed compilation error"? I'm glad you fixed it, but pretending it never happened is pretty lame.

Comment: At first I checked that there is no compilation error and only after added public to class if you mean that

Comment: Skype me to discuss what you thought to produce compilation error rather than messaging here once in half an hour (skype ojosdegris)

Comment: In order to be dull saying it won't produce compilation error, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx, when internal class has public attribute. when you do not specify access modifier class is treated as internal, that is what i have before editing

Comment: If you try to compile your 3rd revision, you will get: "The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". Anyway, you fixed it, so this is really not worth discussing. :)

Comment: as it used to say in Russia - peace - friendship - bubble gum =)

Answer (score 6):

In the interface, it's saying **any** `HtmlControl` can be passed.  You're *narrowing* the scope, by saying only a `HtmlTextArea` can be passed in, so no, you can't do this :)

Picture this example for the reasoning:

```
var btn = new HtmlButton(); //inherits from HtmlControl as well

IExample obj = new Example();
obj.Test(btn); //Uh oh, this *should* take any HtmlControl
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28VS.80%29.aspx). Give the interface a type parameter which is constrained to HtmlControl and its children. Then in your implementation you can either use HtmlControl or a descendant. In this example I'm using HtmlControl, but I'm invoking the Test() method with both HtmlControl and HtmlTextArea:

```
public class HtmlControl {}
public class HtmlTextArea : HtmlControl { }

// if you want to only allow HtmlTextArea, use HtmlTextArea 
// here instead of HtmlControl
public interface IExample<T> where T : HtmlControl
{
    void Test(T ctrl);
}

public class Example : IExample<HtmlControl>
{
    public void Test(HtmlControl ctrl) { Console.WriteLine(ctrl.GetType()); }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IExample<HtmlControl> ex = new Example();
        ex.Test(new HtmlControl());    // writes: HtmlControl            
        ex.Test(new HtmlTextArea());   // writes: HtmlTextArea

    }
}
```