# C# Interface using a child type class

Tags: c#, class, oop, inheritance, interface

Let's say I create this interface :

```
interface Equipable
{
    public bool Equip(Equipment equipment);
}
```

Let's just assume our `Equipment` class is empty for now:

```
class Equipment
{

}
```

I create a derived class from `Equipment` (let's keep it simple):

```
class Trinkets : Equipment
{
    ...
    public Trinkets(...)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then I want a `Trinket` class that implements `Equipable` and that uses its method:

```
class Trinket : Item, Equipable
{
    bool Equipable.Equip(Trinkets trinkets)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

But it seems I can't do this (CS0539), I can't use `Trinkets` class (which however is `Equipment` derived class) as a method parameter of my interface.

This didn't work for me and seems far-fetched: [Implementation of interface when using child class of a parent class in method of interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588524/implementation-of-interface-when-using-child-class-of-a-parent-class-in-method-o).
And it also seems that the above solution does not allow you to use other classes than the base class declared in the interface header.

So my question is simple, is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?
Is it bad practice? If it is, what should I do to overcome this problem?

Comment: I cant follow this well enough to determine what your end goal actually is

Comment: What would you want to happen if someone called `new Trinket().Equip(new SomeOtherEquipment())`? If `Trinket` isn't prepared to equip *any* `Equipment` value, it shouldn't implement `Equipable`.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by the generic proposal sounding "far-fetched" - but you could indeed make your `Equipable` class generic, so that `Trinket` could implement `Equipable<Trinkets>`. (I'd strongly urge you to revisit the naming at the same time, mind you...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description that you need an interface that accepts a reference to `Equipment`. In C#, this means it can accept an object of that class or any derived class on method call. This doesn't include the method implementation.

So `Trinket` should be declared like this:

```
class Trinket : Item, Equipable
{
    bool Equipable.Equip(Equipment equipment)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

But this allows you to call that method passing it an object of type `Equipment` or `Trinkets` as a derived class of `Equipment`. Here's a simple example on that:

```
var trs = new Trinkets();
var eq = new Equipment();

var tr = new Trinket();
tr.Equip(trs);

// Or
tr.Equip(eq);
```

The inheritance will work on object references but not when implementing the method.

Answer (score 0):

On line `bool Equipable.Equip(Trinkets trinkets)`

You specified in the `Equipable` interface that all classes that implement `Equipable` need to contain a defined method called `Equip` that receive an `Equipment` parameter and return a `bool`. The method you defined in the `Trinket` class receive a `Trinket` parameter, so it wont satisfy the condition set out by the interface.

Comment: 1. Well I really wanted a Trinkets class (let's rename it TrincketsPurse, I admit the naming was bad).

2. Yes but Trinket is a child class of Equipment. I thought it should work as an interface is supposed to declare methods implementable in many classes, depending on the class, the method (I thought) should be flexible enough to accept different child class as parameter.